# Question during study Pandas for data science

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = [('California', 2000), ('California', 2010),
         ('New York', 2000), ('New York', 2010),
         ('Texas', 2000), ('Texas', 2010)]

populations = [33871648, 37253956,
                18976457, 19378102,
                20851820, 25145561]

pop = pd.Series(populations, index=index)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
pop = pop.reindex(index)

d1 = pop.loc['California':'New York']
d2 = pop['California':'New York']

print(d1)
print(d2)
print(d1 is d2)
```

'''I don't understand d1 and d2 showing the same result, but why they are different? the last result shows 'False''''

Comment: Because d1 and d2 are 2 seperate objects populated with same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python `is` operator checks if the two arguments are the same object, not if they're `equal`. You can check for example

```
print(id(d1) is id(d2))
```

Will return false because even though d1 and d1 are identical they are essentially clones.